# Docker node-oracledb image build runs into conflict Oracle Instant Client version

Tags: oracle, docker, conflict, node-oracledb, instantclient

I'm not a very savy `docker` developer, and as part of following a tutorial on my company's documents I'm running into an issue while trying to build a docker image using `docker build . -t image_name`.

The issue seems to be complaining about a conflict between two different versions of `Oracle InstantClient`. I was wondering if anyone with prior experience can help me with it.

```
Loaded plugins: ovl
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package node-oracledb-node12.x86_64 0:4.1.0-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: oracle-instantclient19.3-basic >= 19.3.0.0.0 for package: node-oracledb-node12-4.1.0-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package nodejs.x86_64 0:12.18.1-1.0.1.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package oracle-instantclient19.3-basic.x86_64 0:19.3.0.0.0-1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: oracle-instantclient19.5-basic-19.5.0.0.0-1.x86_64 conflicts libclntsh.so.19.1
--> Processing Conflict: oracle-instantclient19.3-basic-19.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64 conflicts libclntsh.so.19.1
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: oracle-instantclient19.5-basic conflicts with oracle-instantclient19.3-basic-19.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64
Error: oracle-instantclient19.3-basic conflicts with oracle-instantclient19.5-basic-19.5.0.0.0-1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y install oracle-release-el7 && yum-config-manager --enable ol7_oracle_instantclient     && yum -y install oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-basic oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-devel oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-sqlplus     && yum install -y oracle-nodejs-release-el7 oracle-release-el7     && yum-config-manager --enable ol7_developer_nodejs12     && yum -y install nodejs node-oracledb-node12     && rm -rf /var/cache/yum     && yum -y upgrade' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The main part of my dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim

ARG release=19
ARG update=5

RUN yum -y install oracle-release-el7 && yum-config-manager --enable ol7_oracle_instantclient \
    && yum -y install oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-basic --skip-broken oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-devel oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-sqlplus \
    && yum install -y oracle-nodejs-release-el7 oracle-release-el7 \
    && yum-config-manager --enable ol7_developer_nodejs12 \
    && yum -y install nodejs node-oracledb-node12 \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/yum \
    && yum -y upgrade
```

Comment: The issue is not Docker related. Review what you are installing with `yum`. That's where the issue is.

Comment: Guess you're trying to build node docker container follow [instructions](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#docker) here

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle Linux group pushed out some updated Dockerfiles in the last day or so.  The Node.js 12 file is at https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleLinuxDevelopers/oraclelinux7/nodejs/12-oracledb/Dockerfile.

Also see the node-oracledb installation instructions for docker: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#docker

And see the blog post series https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1

You can try:

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim

RUN yum -y install oracle-nodejs-release-el7 oracle-release-el7 && \
    yum -y install nodejs node-oracledb-node12 && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*

ENV NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules

CMD ["/bin/node", "-v"]
```

Comment: Hey @Christopher-jones, thanks for your insight. I have edited my question and added the main part of my docker file. Since I'm not a very experienced docker user and I'm in a big rush, would you mind looking at it and tailor your response more specifically to it?

Comment: Except for the `yum -y upgrade` (which you would do before the `rm`), my answer already does what I _think_ you want.  Give it a try.